what is a good way to change unsigned minus unsigned to be signed?
I just found unsigned minus unsigned is quite strange when you have a negative number.
For example,
unsigned a = 2;
unsigned b = 0;
unsigned c = 1;
unsigned d = 3;
unsigned e = 4;
unsigned f = 0;
double ans = (a-b)*(c-d)/(e-f);

ans will not be the value you expect.
What is a good way to define ans?
if I do double ans = (double)(a-b)*(c-d)/(e-f), it is not correct either.

you really should not be doing math with unsigned types.  Signed types are for math, unsigned types are for binary data.  if a 32 bit signed is not big enough then go 64 bit signed.  That'll handle any practical number.

And using floating point is rarely a good way to do integer maths

Incidentally, double ans = (a-b)*(c-d)/(e-f); does the arithmetic with unsigned int and converts the result to double. So it's no better than unsigned an = ....

If you can expect to get negative numbers, you need to use signed types. There is no way to define ans that will get you the number you expect based on the types of your other variables.

Noone knows. Everything will be optimized away. Put your calculations in context please.

Pete Becker's point is vital. The type you store the result of a computation to has absolutely no effect on how the computation is performed. If the result was damaged due to limitations of the type used in the computation, the result come out damaged and be stored damaged. And the conversion to the final type can damage the result as well. The classic example of this is pow(5,2) spitting out 24.9999999999 and being truncated to 24 when converted to an integer.

"you really should not be doing math with unsigned types" - well, that depends entirely on your domain and range. If both of those are the set of non-negative integers, unsigned int is fine. That's not the case here as the range of c-d includes negative numbers but the assertion about not using unsigned should be qualified.

"when you have a negative number" -- You cannot have a negative unsigned value. I think you mean "when the difference would be negative (mathematically)".

"ans will not be the value you expect." -- It will not? I expect it to have the value 1073741823 (because I know how to do computer arithmetic). What value will ans have? My point is to provide details. State the value you get. State the value you expect and why; don't assume everyone is coming from the same place as you.

With unsigned integral types, overflow is well defined. For 32-bit integers, therefore, (c-d) evaluates to 4'294'967'294. (a-b) is 2, so (a-b)*(c-d) generates another overflow, producing  4'294'967'292. Since (e-f) is 4, (a-b)*(c-d)/(e-f) equals 4'294'967'292 / 4, which is 1'073'741'823. All 32-bits are preserved when this value is used to copy-initialize the double ans, which has a 53-bit mantissa in IEEE-754 implementations.

Just like with division, you need to convert the operands to double before the operation. Just having a double variable won't work. See the linked duplicate.

"ans will not be the value you expect" Me?

Reopened. The problem isn't the division; it's the subtraction.

@PeteBecker Incidentally, it is actually the division and multiplication causing the problem here, plus the conversion to double, paradoxically. Only adding and subtracting in two's complement would yield the same bit patterns whether performed signed or unsigned, so that converting the result to an int (not to a float) would yield the "expected" result.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica -- "it could do what is expected" is not the same as "it's correct". The underlying problem is that c-d is not a negative number, despite d being greater than c. Arithmetic is not about bit patterns; it's about values.
